# are almost everywhere bounded functions measurable?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

We know that if $f : [a,b] → R$ is measurable, then $f$ is “almost
bounded” on $[a,b]$ in the sense that, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is an open set $G$ with
$\ell(G) < \epsilon$ such that $f$ is bounded on the closed set $[a,b]\setminus G$.

Indeed:

for each integer $n$, let
$$E_n = \{x ∈ [a,b] : | f (x)| > n\}.$$
These sets all have finite Lebesgue measures, they form a decreasing sequence
of sets and
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n=\emptyset.$$
Consequently $\ell(E_n)\rightarrow 0$. Now just take an integer $N$ so that $\ell(E_N)<\epsilon/2$ and use
$E = E_N$. Observe that $| f (x)| \le N$ for all $x \in [a,b]\setminus E$. Since $l(E) < \epsilon/2$ we can also find an open set $G\supseteq E$ for which $\ell(G) < \epsilon$ and for which the statement of the theorem must hold.

Is the contrary true? That is: are almost everywhere bounded functions measurable?

Answer (score 7):

If $E$ is any non-measurable set and $f=\chi_E$ (i.e. $f(x)=1$ for $x \in E$, $0$ for $x \notin E$ ) then $f$ satisfies your hypothesis (for any open set $G$!) but $f$ is not measurable.

Comment: So the matter is even more radical, that is, there are even bounded functions that are not measurable. Thank you so much